# Adding/cumulating "line chart components"

Tags: java, algorithm, charts

I can imagine that there is some algorithmic problem which exactly describes my problem but I could not find any. What I basically want to do is:

Let's say, I have some data structure with an object of type Line which contains two (or more, but in my case two is enough) objects of type Point(x, y).

A Line represents a line in a line chart from one point A(x, y) to another point B(x, y).

Now I have a list of such lines. Note, that they may also overlap in their x-coordinates. For example I have a line from (0, 0) to (3, 1) and another line from (2, 0) to (3, 2). I now want to "cumulate" this list of lines and have a list of points as a result (to draw a line chart later).

For the above example that would mean that I want {(0, 0); (2, 0,67); (3, 2)}. Here is a beautiful image which hopefully makes my issue more clear:

[image: line chart]

**Background:** I am programming a blood alcohol content level calculator. I have several drinks with attributes like: volume, percent, start time, end time.

I want to assume a linear rise of the blood alcohol content level from the start time to the end time minus the alcohol reduction during that time period. In my thoughts, it would be now easy to calculate the single "lines" of each drinks, but to get a full line chart representing your blood alcohol content level over the whole time, I would now have to "add"/"cumulate" all those "lines" together.

At least that were my thoughts and this would be my approach, if you have different approaches/suggestions, please let me know as well.

Comment: _Here is a beautiful image which hopefully makes my issue more clear_. 1. You're a ms paint artist. :). 2. Yep, it makes it clear.

Comment: Are your charts continuous or discrete?. In other words: can exist a point like this: `(1.023,7.21)` ?

Comment: I hope, I got you right: For my special use, I would have a time of data type `Date` as x-variable (the library I am using accepts this, I guess, it's being converted to a timestamp of data type `long` later) and the blood alcohol content level of data type `double` as y-variable.

Comment: I would do the following: first, break down the lines into more lines so that for each pair of lines, the only overlaps occuring are equalities (you can do that by looking at the start and end x of each line) in your example, you break the first line in two parts, at x=2 ; then, group your lines with equal start and end x and add the y values to get a single line for each group.

Comment: @user1684030 Do you need the lines to be considered as lines? I mean, can be a line considered as a succesion of points?

Comment: @user1684030 I have the solution. In a couple of hours I'll post the answer.

Comment: To answer your previous question anyway: Lines can rather be considered as a list of Points, you are right, I noticed that while trying to find a solution, too. I also came closer, but I didn't really get a proper working algorithm yet. So I am really excited about your solution! Looking forward to see it.

Comment: @user1684030 Done! check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea of the algorithm:

1. Split the x axis into intervals.
   The points defining the intervals correspond to the 'x' attribute of each point of each line.

[image: Intervals]

2. Summation of the lines contained in the intervals.
   Now we generate a new line per interval. This line will be the summation of the lines contained in that interval.
3. In order to be able to sum two lines, we transform both lines into functions ([Slope y-intercept form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Slope.E2.80.93intercept_form)), we perform the sum and we create a new line.

The slope intercept form for the equation of any straight line is given by:

```
y = mx + b
```

where:

1. m is the slope of the line
2. b is the y-intercept of the line

The slope m of the line through any two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` is given by:

[image: Slope_formula]

The y-intercept b of the line is the value of y at the point where the line crosses the y axis. Since for point `(x1, y1)` we have `y1 = mx1 + b`, the y-intercept b can be calculated by:

```
b = y1 - mx1
```

The 'x' values of the points of the new line will be the limits of the interval, the 'y' values will be the result of applying the function to the 'x' value.

The code: *(Note: Getters/setters are ommited)*

LineFunction:

```
public class LineFunction {

    private final double m, b;

    public LineFunction(Line l) {
        /**
         * y= ((y_b-y_a)/(x_b-x_a))*(x-x_a) + y_a
         * 
         * ((y_b-y_a)/(x_b-x_a))==> m
         * 
         * y = m *(x-x_a)+y_a
         * 
         * y= m*x -m*x_a +y_a
         * 
         * -m*x_a +y_a -> b
         * 
         * y = m*x + b
         */
        double y_a, y_b, x_a, x_b;
        x_a = l.getP1().getX();
        y_a = l.getP1().getY();
        x_b = l.getP2().getX();
        y_b = l.getP2().getY();
        m = (y_b - y_a) / (x_b - x_a);
        b = -m * x_a + y_a;

    }

    private LineFunction(double m, double b) {
        this.m = m;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public double computeFor(double xValue) {
        return this.m * xValue + this.b;
    }

    public LineFunction sum(LineFunction other) {
        return new LineFunction(this.m + other.m, this.b + other.b);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "y = " + m + "x + " + b;
    }
}
```

This class represent a simple function of type *y = mx + b* . Basically, takes a line and transforms it into a function.

Line:

```
public class Line {

    private final Point p1, p2;
    private final LineFunction lineFunction;

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.lineFunction = new LineFunction(this);
    }
    public Line(Line o) {
        this.p1 = o.p1;
        this.p2 = o.p2;
        this.lineFunction = new LineFunction(this);
    }
    public Line sum(Line other,Point p1,Point p2) {
        LineFunction s= this.lineFunction.sum(other.lineFunction);
        return new Line(new Point(p1.getX(),s.computeFor(p1.getX())),new Point(p2.getX(),s.computeFor(p2.getX())));
    }
    public boolean isInInterval(Point p) {
        return p.getX() >= this.p1.getX() && p.getX() < this.p2.getX();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{"+p1+","+p2+"}";
    }

}
```

A `Line` is defined by two points, and from a `Line` we can get the function that defines it. It has methods for checking if the *x* value of a point is between the starting and ending *x* of the line.

In order to accomplish the point 1 of the algorithm, we need to know all the points of every line:

```
public static ArrayList<Point> getAllPoints(ArrayList<Line> lines) {
        HashSet<Point> points = new HashSet<Point>();
        for (Line line : lines)
        {
            points.add(line.getP1());
            points.add(line.getP2());
        }
        ArrayList<Point> res = new ArrayList<Point>(points);
        Collections.sort(res);
        return res;
    }
```

This method returns all the points defining the intervals. The points must be ordered, so

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
    private long x;
    private double y;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Point o) {
        int cmp1=Long.compare(this.x, o.x);
        return  cmp1 != 0 ? cmp1 : Double.compare(this.y, o.y) ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (x ^ (x >>> 32));
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.y))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

For the second step of the algorithm, we need to know wich lines belong to a given interval:

```
public static ArrayList<Line> filter(Point p, ArrayList<Line> lines) {
        ArrayList<Line> filtered = new ArrayList<Line>();
        for (Line line : lines)
            if (line.isInInterval(p))
                filtered.add(line);

        return filtered;
    }
```

The only thing left is the summation of a groups of lines:

```
public static ArrayList<Line> sumAll(ArrayList<Line> lines) {
        ArrayList<Point> points = getAllPoints(lines);
        ArrayList<Line> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            Point current = points.get(i);
            Point next = points.get(i + 1);
            ArrayList<Line> filtered = filter(current, lines);
            Line acc = new Line(new Point(current.getX(), 0), new Point(
                    next.getX(), 0));

            for (Line lf : filtered)
            {
                acc = acc.sum(lf, current, next);
            }

            result.add(acc);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

A simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Line l1 = new Line(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 1));
        Line l2 = new Line(new Point(2, 0), new Point(3, 1));

        Line l3 = new Line(new Point(4, 7), new Point(8, 2));
        Line l4 = new Line(new Point(5, 4), new Point(6, 1));

        Line l5 = new Line(new Point(9, 6), new Point(10, 1));
        ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        lines.add(l1);
        lines.add(l2);
        lines.add(l3);
        lines.add(l4);
        lines.add(l5);
        ArrayList<Line> res = sumAll(lines);
        for (Line line : res)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }


    }
```

Output:

```
{(0,0.0),(2,0.6666666666666666)}
{(2,0.666666666666667),(3,2.0)}
{(3,0.0),(4,0.0)} ----> There's no line in this interval.
{(4,7.0),(5,5.75)}
{(5,9.75),(6,5.5)}
{(6,4.5),(8,2.0)}
{(8,0.0),(9,0.0)}
{(9,6.0),(10,1.0)}
```

If I'm missing anything, don't hesitate lo leave a comment.

Comment: You perfectly solved the problem, therefore I will mark this thread as solved. However, I noticed, that I wasn't thinking far enough. I would need more than just adding sections of the graph, I also need to keep the offset for later sections. Here is an image to illustrate what I mean: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140605/fbzlm9vo.jpg - I'll try further on my own, maybe your solution can help me. Thanks a lot anyway! I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Additionally, I am struggling with the actual alcohol degradation. I was thinking of adding a "Line" from ([the beginning of the graph], 0.0) to ([the time of the end of the day/graph], [computed degradation (negative number)]), but then I would have negative results. I would need this "degradation line" to affect the other lines only after they "went positive". Difficult to explain, this image might help: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140605/b48icxvy.jpg

Comment: As you can see, I made a few mistakes in my thoughts and I am really sorry if you feel like you wasted your time... :( You solved the explained issue and, again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1684030 Don't worry.I'm happy to help. If you need anything else, create a new question and let me know. I will answer gladly.